# fixated at, on, or to?

Tags: grammar

Can I use the following expressions?
What are the differences between them?

> 1. The stick is fixated on the table.
> 2. The stick is fixated at the table.
> 3. The stick is fixated to the table.

Comment: The correct preposition is "on". You could replace it with "focus" for instance. Another possibility is "upon", e.g.: "I used to be fixated upon (by someone)." It works when the subject is not the one fixating, but the object of the fixation.

Comment: **on** is always the correct preposition for *fixated*, but I don't think *fixated* means what you think it means.  Did you look it up?

Comment: *The stick is **fixed to** the table*. Or just *The stick is on the table* depending on what you (erroneously) thought ***fixate*** means.

Comment: What _English language_ dictionary do you use? I don't mean a dictionary that translates your first language into English, but an English dictionary such as [**Oxford Learner's Dictionary.**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/) What does that dictionary tell you about the verb _fixate?_

Answer (score 3):

I would say all the three statements are wrong, because of the verb used there (fixate).
Before telling why, I would cite the definitions and examples for the verb 'fixate'.

The verb fixate is defined by Google in several ways, which I have listed below:

> verb
>
> past tense: fixated; past participle: fixated
>
> 1. cause (someone) to develop an obsessive attachment to someone or something.
>
>    "he became fixated on the idea of a Third World War"
>
>    - develop a fixation with.
>
>    "erotomaniacs are convinced that the person they have fixated on loves them in return"
>
>    - (in Freudian theory) arrest (a person or their libidinal energy) at an immature stage, causing an obsessive attachment.
>
>    "an individual may have been fixated at one stage of development"
> 2. technical
>
>    direct one's eyes towards.
>      "subjects fixated a central point"

This verb is never to be used in the place of 'fixed'.

As far as stick and table are concerned, it can be said as, "the stick is lying on the table". (Even the verb 'fix' doesn't work here.)

Comment: I agree with you up to the last sentence. You could say, "The stick is fixed to the table" meaning "firmly attached to the table". (Well, you could also say "the stick was fixed on the table" meaning that it was broken and then someone put it on a table and repaired it while it was on the table, but that's a very different meaning of "fixed".)

Comment: OP may be confusing *fixated* and *affixed*.

Comment: https://www.google.co.kr/search?tbm=pts&hl=ko&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=fixated+to&gbv=2&oq=fixated+to&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3..0i30j0i8i30l2.2772.4050.0.4454.10.10.0.0.0.0.221.1027.5j3j1.9.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..3.7.669.EQaFeJO-UOY

Comment: fix•ate
 (ˈfɪk seɪt) 

v. -at•ed, -at•ing. v.t. 
1. to fix; make stable or stationary.

Comment: I searched google patent by the keyword "fixated to", and found innumerable patent documents. Many of them come from europe, but some from US. In addition, when I looked up the word at thefreedictionary.com, it says as above (fixate =to fix, make stable or stationary). Why is it that almost all native speakers deny using "fixate something to" as instead of "fix something to"? I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Never copy and paste without clearly indicating what is a quote and what is not.